# MAils automation using selenium with user input and adding attachement to mail

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate mails using selenium, now i have a situation that i want to get the input from the user for selection according to the user i will ahve to select mail clients

say gmail nd yahoo

If the user selects gmail a block of code should run

and for other it should execute the other..

I need to attach a document in mail, i am able to click on the attach file icon after that the windows message pops up to select document i am not able to move through in that.

Is there any way to attach file

Can anyone help me on this

Please be explain in detail since i am new to selenium

Thanks...